# Recurrence relation non homogeneus issue

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

i need to solve this recursive equation, but im get stuck in the non homogeneous part:

$$T_{n}=T_{n-1}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$$

according to theory must be: 
$$ a_{0}T_{n}+...+a_{k}T_{n-k}=b^{n}p(n)$$

$$(a_{0}x^{k}+...+a_{k})(x-b)^{d+1}=0 $$ $$d:degree$$

$$(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})^3=0$$

$$T_{n}=C_{1}*1^{n}+C_{2}*(\frac{1}{2})^{n}+C_{3}*(\frac{1}{2})^{n}*n+C_{4}*(\frac{1}{2})^{n}*n^{2}$$

dont know if this procedure is right, the result must be $$T_{n}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$ but cant rech it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ T_k-T_{k-1} = \binom{k+1}{2}\tag{1} $$
hence by summing both sides of $(1)$ over $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ and exploiting the [Hockey stick identity](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity) (and the fact that the sum of the LHSs is a telescopic sum) we get:
$$ T_n-T_0 = \binom{n+2}{3} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{6}\tag{2} $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the approach you'd like to use 
$$
T_{n}=T_{n-1}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\to T_n-T_{n-1}=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}
$$

$$
a_{0}T_{n}+a_{1}T_{n-1}=b^{n}p(n),
$$
where $a_0=1,a_1=-1,b=1,p(n)=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2},d=deg(p(n))=2$.

Hence, equation $(a_{0}x^{k}+...+a_{k})(x-b)^{d+1}=0$ transforms to:
$$
(x-1)(x-1)^3=(x-1)^4=0
$$

And respective solution for $T_n$ should be:
$$
\begin{align}
T_n&=C_11^n+C_21^nn+C_31^nn^2+C_41^nn^3\\
&=C_1+C_2n+C_3n^2+C_4n^3
\end{align}
$$
In which we can simply plug values of $n$, e.g. $\{0,1,2,3\}$ to define constants $C_i$.

Comment: Thanks!! now i see what was my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{m}T_{n}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}T_{n - 1} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{m}n^{2} +
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{m}n
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{m - 1}T_{n} +
{1 \over 2}\bracks{{1 \over 6}\,m\pars{m + 1}\pars{2m + 1}} +
{1 \over 2}\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,m\pars{m + 1}}
\\[5mm] &=
T_{0} - T_{m} + \color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{m}T_{n}} + {1 \over 6}\,m^{3} +
{1 \over 2}\,m^{2} + {1 \over 3}\,m\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$$
\eqref{1}\implies\bbox[0.5em,border:0.15em groove navy]{\color{#f00}{T_{n}} =
\color{#f00}{T_{0} + {1 \over 6}\,n^{3} + {1 \over 2}\,n^{2} + {1 \over 3}\,n}}
$$